# UIScrollView w/ zoom doesn't scroll until zoomed

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll, zooming

I have a UIScrollView loaded with a UIImageView, so that the user can zoom in, and then scroll if necessary. However, if the image is larger than the screen, scrolling doesn't do anything until the user pinches to zoom (even just one pixel). For example, the image might be 320 x 600, so they see a section 320 x 480, but would have to scroll to see the rest. However, the scrolling wouldn't work until they zoomed in or out. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you called -setContentSize: on the scroll view? If you haven't, it won't know that there is offscreen content to display.

Comment: I can't believe this simple solution could solve this problem. tnx

Answer (score 3):

Was stuck on this problem for almost a whole day.  In the far right window, click on the far left button like so[image: screenshot]

Then uncheck the "Use Autolayout"

Comment: I have experienced auto-layout modifying my scrollviews' content size in certain scenarios.  In the situation that auto-layout is _also_ required you can modify your scrollviews' content size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` rather than `viewDidLoad`